# English to Arabic conversion in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I want to translate English to Arabic in wordpress (buddy press).

In php

```
$reason        = __(sprintf("Wave limit has been exceeded for today, you can wave %s tomorrow",$user),"buddypress");
```

In buddypress.pot

```
#: wave
msgid "Wave limit has been exceeded for today, you can wave %s tomorrow"
msgstr "تم تجاوز الحد موجة لهذا اليوم، يمكنك موجة٪ S غدا"
```

My problem is that message is not converting. If I remove %s it isworking fine. ie Dynamically creating a message is failing.

Comment: I have zero familiarity with WordPress, but have you checked you're using the right encoding, and that you have PHP's `mbstring` extension installed?

Comment: I belive your msgstr should be `???? %s ???`. You've got something else instead of **`%s`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php we should call like this

```
$reason    = sprintf(__("Wave limit has been exceeded for today, you can wave  tomorrow %s","buddypress"),$user);
```